# Infermedica API integration with RASA chatbot

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

How to connect Infermedica API with RASA chatbot? Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You can call APIs in **Custom Actions**

for example, take a look at this [Github Code from Rasa](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-demo/tree/main/actions)